# How to jump the top of the file in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Does anyone know if there's a shortcut key on Mac for going directly to the top of the file? (Or, for that matter, the bottom?) I can't find one so for now I'm using Cmd-G, 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

If your keyboard lacks <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys, use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>→</kbd>  ([reference](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/))

You can always change the default shortcuts in PhpStorm `Preferences` | `Keymap`:

[image]

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much! :)

In case it's useful for others with a similar problem, I should add that shortcuts that work well (because they aren't used for other things) for the MacBook Pro (which has no Home and End keys) are:

`Move to Text Start: Alt-up-arrow
Move to Text End: Alt-down-arrow`

Comment: Could not find the actual name of the action until I read this.

Comment: just a small note, the latest version of PHPstorm and newer versions of Mac OS uses Alt-up-arrow to expand the selection, whilst Alt-down-arrow decreases the current selection.

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d617165e275 (you need to change to Mac OS X 10.5+)

Comment: If you're on a keyboard without Home/End, you don't have to do the Keymap thing. cmd-fn-left-arrow takes you to the top and cmd-fn-right-arrow takes you to the bottom.

Comment: **Page Up**   (fn-Up Arrow on compact keyboards)

**Page Down**   (fn-Down Arrow on compact keyboards)